# What is the difference between b'\xffff' and b'\xff\xff'?

Tags: python, binary, byte

In Python 3.8, I noticed the interger conversion of `b'\xFFFF'` and `b'\xFF\xFF'` are different:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xffff', 'big')
16737894
```

whose binary representation is:
`1111 1111 0110 0110 0110 0110`,

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xff\xff', 'big')
65535
```

whose binary representation is what I expected:
`1111 1111`,

But why is `b'\xFFFF'` so different?

Comment: Hint: what happens if you try `list(b'\xffff')`? Hint 2: what happens if you try `list(b'f')`? Hint 3: what does the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) say about `\x` escapes?

Comment: In other words: for the same reason that `print('\nn')` doesn't print two blank lines.

Comment: I understand now. The `\x` takes in exactly two bytes, the extra characters will be interpreted as ASCII values.

Comment: The first bytes value, `b'\xffff'`, is equivalent to `b'\xff\x66\x66`.  In fact, they both print as `b'\xffff'`.  The first two `f` characters are part of the 8-bit code `\xff`.  The other two `f` characters are just printable `f` characters whose 8-bit codes are `\x66`.